# TabController and Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I would like to display the AsyncValue result from a Riverpod StatenotifierProvider in a TabControl. In a StatefulWidget I would have implemented the TabController like so:

```
class Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  Screen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Screen> createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends State<Screen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }
```

If I convert this widget to a ConsumerWidget I can no longer mix in the TickerProvider and if I stick with the StatefulWidget I don't have access to the ref and therby the provider.

Would appreciate you help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `ConsumerStatefulWidget` to access `ref` (and use `TickerProviderStateMixin` mixin) in this way:

```dart
class Screen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const Screen({super.key});

  @override
  _ScreenState createState() => _ScreenState();
}

class _ScreenState extends ConsumerState<Screen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  late final TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // "ref" can be used in all life-cycles of a StatefulWidget.
    ref.read(currentIndexProvider);

    _tabController = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final index = ref.watch(currentIndexProvider);
    return Text('$index');
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

More info [ConsumerStatefulWidget](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_riverpod/latest/flutter_riverpod/ConsumerStatefulWidget-class.html).

Comment: @TecHaxter Thanks for the message! I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score -1):

At the end I decided to go with the [tab_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/tab_container) package rather than with the TabController. The look is similar and it resulted in a cleaner code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).